# I'm addicted to drugs: what will delay the withdrawal?

Tags: die2nite

In order to give the town a sliver of a chance to survive one more night, I was forced to take two steroids in one day and now I'm hooked! Which drugs can I take each day to stave off my inevitable death? Does it have to be steroids or will any drug work? For instance, will water purification tablets work? (I'm guessing no.)

Comment: I don't really think that this question is appropriate here... Oh, you're talking about die2nite. Of course you are.

Comment: Just coincidence that this question is being asked by someone with MD in their name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drugs that can be taken to prevent death from withdrawal

- Twinoid
- Betapropine
- Steroids
- Unlabelled drug
- Valium
- Hydratone
- Paracetoid

In general, you should try to stick to the drugs that are less useful to others.  Unlabelled drugs are good because anyone else that takes them is likely to get addicted.  Same with Betapropine.  Paracetoid might be a good option if your town has lots and nobody is getting infected.  Hydratone is a good option if you're thirsty and aren't going to drink.  Valium is generally not useful until the end, but its quite important then.  And Twinoid and Steroids should be last resorts unless you need the AP from them anyways.

Answer (score 5):

From the die2nite help on Health:

> When you take too many drugs (more
>   than one per day), you become Addicted
>   ! It is impossible to kick this habit.
>
> From this point onwards, you must
>   consume at least one drug every day
>   before midnight, or you will die
>   (foaming at the mouth and shaking
>   uncontrolably, it's spectactularly
>   unattractive...).

You have to take one of any drug each day.

Comment: I think Java wanted some more specific information :)

Comment: There is nothing more to say. He is now permanently addicted (unless he dies and is reborn) and he has to take 1 of any drug each day to survive.

Comment: The question was really *which* drugs will work to keep me alive and which won't.

Comment: He said that any drug will work. In my last town a dude took the drug that cures infection for his addiction, and a hero that had an infection died because of it.

Comment: Water purification tablets are in the bank next to drugs that are obviously drugs. Are they a drug? Is everything or only some things listed in that category a drug?

Comment: can you eat water purification tablets? also, if a bandage and a anti infection are classed as drugs, does taking both of them get you addicted?

Comment: Bandages do not count.  I'm pretty sure it just means that anything in pill form that you can 'take' will keep you alive.  Well, everything but a cyanide pill.

Answer (score 1):

anything listed under Drugs is a drug.

Comment: Listed where? If you mean in the "Pharmacy" section of the bank, this is incorrect. I just tried to eat water purification tablets and you can't. So clearly some things are drugs, others aren't.